# Setting the Geometry with sql query

Tags: shapefile, sql, carto, query, united-states

I am trying to merge data from a U.S. states shapefile with data on each state. I used this SQL query which is supposed to work:

```
 SELECT * FROM child_poverty_by_state
 UPDATE child_poverty_by_state
 SET the_geom = us_states.the_geom
 FROM us_states
 WHERE us_states.state = child_poverty_by_state.state
```

The table "us_states" which is the shapefile, doesn't auto-populate in the query. Not sure why, is there an error with my query?

Comment: What software are you using to do this. A shapefile is not a database, and the query you are using is specific to a spatial database (ie: Spatialite, PostGIS, etc.). If you want to do those types of queries you will want to put your data into a spatial database (like the types mentioned above).

Comment: I'm not using any software I'm just using Cartodb. I have a separate shapefile that's uploaded as a table that I was trying to merge with the child_poverty_by_state table. All I'm trying to do is a have a U.S. map that shows child poverty rates by state. Any advice on what I should do since this isn't working?

Comment: Without looking at the data it is a little difficult for me, but you could look at table joins or spatial joins. I am assuming you have some data with birth rates (points or polygons). If the birth rates data has any attributes related to the state, then you could do a table join with the state polygon to put that data into the state table. Otherwise, you may want to do a spatial join. Going about this will depend on how your data is put together.

Answer (score 1):

When you create child_poverty_by_state, you need to create the geometry table with the following, assuming you are working in WGS84 ..

```
ALTER TABLE child_poverty_by_state ADD COLUMN the_geom geometry(POINT,4326);
```

You also need to ensure that the geometry column has the correct srid, it is not always added from the shape-file, for example for WGS84 ...

```
UPDATE us_states SET the_geom = ST_SetSRID(the_geom,4326);
```